# Generically Register All Concrete types for Lazy Loading in DI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to setup Lazy Loading of registered types in a generic way that does not require me to register each one individually.

I can create an extension method to simultaneously register lazily like so:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddLazyTransient<T>(this IServiceCollection services) 
    where T : class
{
    return services
        .AddTransient<T>()
        .AddTransient<Func<T>>(s => s.GetRequiredService<T>);
}
```

Which works fine, until unfortunately when my `T` now a `Type`, for example I am using Assembly style registration to get all classes in my WPF project which inherit from `Window` like so:

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterWindows<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var assemblyName = typeof(T).Assembly.FullName ??
        throw new ApplicationException(
            $"No assembly name for type '{typeof(T).FullName}'");
    var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyName);

    var windowTypes = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Window)))
        .ToList();

    foreach (var windowType in windowTypes)
    {
        services.AddTransient(windowType);

        // But how do I register a Func<Type> here now?

    }

    return services;
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
var windowFuncType = Expression.GetFuncType(windowType);
services.AddTransient(windowFuncType, s => () => s.GetRequiredService(windowType));
```

But that gives the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type System.Func'1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Func'1[MyApp.Wpf.MainWindow]'.'

Which makes sense. `ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(Type)` returns an `object`, so I am registering a `Func<object>` when it is expecting a `Func<MainWindow>`

So I need to convert `Func<object>` to `Func<Type>` manually via reflection, in the middle of the registration, how do I do that though?

Comment: `var windowFuncType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(windowType);`

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to inject factories on that scale? Object composition should in general be very fast limiting the need for postponing the creation of dependencies using factory delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this, but the simplest that comes to my mind is to just call the generic `AddLazyTransient<T>` method using reflection from inside the non-generic `AddLazyTransient` method. For instance:

```cs
public static void AddLazyTransient(this IServiceCollection services, Type type)
{
    // Define an expression that contains a reference to the method to call
    Expression<Action> expression = () => AddLazyTransient<object>(null);

    // Extract the method from the expression
    var addLazyTransientOfObject = ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method;

    // Convert it to a generic type definition.
    var addLazyTransientOfT = addLazyTransientOfObject.GetGenericMethodDefinition();

    // Convert it to the exact closed method definition we require
    var addLazyTransientOfType = addLazyTransientOfT.MakeGenericMethod(type);

    // Call the method with its required parameter.
    addLazyTransientOfType.Invoke(null, new[] { services });
}
```

There are certainly other ways of tackling this problem, such as calling `AddTransient` by supplying a `typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(type)` and a delegate that is compiled from the original `Func<object>` with a cast, which can be done using `Expression.Convert`, `Expression.Invoke`, and `Expression.Lambda.Compile()`, but as I said, I think this is easier.

Comment: Nice, works like a charm! I feel like Expression reflection like this is the next big hurdle I need to dig into for more advanced C# functionality.