# WPF : How to do dependency injection when ViewModels and Views are in separate projects?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection

I have this WPF app with MVVM pattern, now I want to do dependency injection in my project, but I found myself in trouble. My App has below construction:

```
MyApp
|----MyApp.ViewModels
|----MyApp.Views
```

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection), I need to initiate my dependency injection services in the App.Xaml.cs file which is in MyApp.Views project.

Say I have two viewmodels in MyApp.ViewModels project:

```cs
public class ViewModelAlpha{
    private IDialogService _dialogService;
    private ViewModelBeta viewModelBeta;
    public ViewModelAlpha(IDialogService dialogService){
        _dialogService = dialogService;
    }
}

public class ViewModelBeta{
    private IDialogService _dialogService;
    public ViewModelBeta(IDialogService dialogService){
        _dialogService = dialogService;
    }
}
```

So, ViewModelAlpha has a ViewModelBeta **singleton** as its field, what should I do to **lazy initiate** ViewModelBeta in ViewModelAlpha? I don't want to initiate ViewModelBeta until it's required. What I'm currently doing is provide a static *Instance* in ViewModelBeta:

```
public class ViewModelBeta{
    private static ViewModelBeta instance;
    public static ViewModelBeta Instance {
         return instance ?? new ViewModelBeta();
    }
    public ViewModelBeta(){ ... }
}
```

What I can think of is to change the Instance property to something like :

```
public static ViewModelBeta Instance {
    return instance ?? 
        ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ViewModelBeta>();
}
```

But since ServiceProvider is created in the MyApp.Views project, how should I get it in MyApp.ViewModels project.

Comment: You haven't explained why you need `ViewModelBeta` to be instantiated lazily. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Steven, I have lots of modules (ViewModels), not all of the are required. Some VMs are required only when my App is set to a certain mode.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that [injection constructors should be simple and therefore fast](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). If injection of them causes performance problems, this might be caused by injection constructors doing more than just storing their dependencies. This might be an issue to tackle first, because when fixed, the problem that triggered your question is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer for a similar question I had, for a similar use case, was quite helpful.

[Generically Register All Concrete types for Lazy Loading in DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138519/generically-register-all-concrete-types-for-lazy-loading-in-di)

The end result is you can register an `IYourInterface` and it will also register a `Func<IYourInterface>` you can inject and invoke when ready to load it.

All the `Func<T>` does is request that same interface from the DI engine, allowing you to lazy load it.

In my case it was registering all the `Window` classes I had implemented in my assembly, but it can be applied to any use case, the handy answer is a nice generic way that utilizes expression reflection to compose the `Func<T>` on the fly.

You can see here in another of my projects I extended the functionality out to create a suite of similar methods for all the standard registrations on `ServiceCollection`

https://github.com/SteffenBlake/PoeFilterX/blob/main/src/PoeFilterX/Extensions/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer did answer a part of my question. But what should I do when ViewModels and Views are in separate projects?

Comment: You can reference one project from another, the project doing the injecting just has to have a reference to the project where the object definitions were declared.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem before where some dependencies might cost extra memory to initiate at the constructor, in your case, view models.

In general, this problem might be similar to **transient** services where you in some situations will resolve them using `IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>()` and soon after getting rid of their references for less memory consumption.

And to use the service provider, the best way is to inject it into your service constructor as a dependency, so for the case of your view model:

```cs
public ViewModelAlpha(IDialogService dialogService, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _dialogService = dialogService;
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}
```

And then you can add a property to lazy load `ViewModelBeta` whenever needed:

```cs
public class ViewModelAlpha
{
    private ViewModelBeta? _viewModelBeta;
    private ViewModelBeta ViewModelBeta
    {
        get => _viewModelBeta ??= _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ViewModelBeta>();
    }
        
    // Dependencies.
    private IDialogService _dialogService;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ViewModelAlpha(IDialogService dialogService, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _dialogService = dialogService;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

> But since ServiceProvider is created in the MyApp.Views project, how
> should I get it in MyApp.ViewModels project.

Having the `ServiceProvider` injected into your startup project (MyApp.Views) doesn't mean that core library services can't have it as a dependency. In fact, it's a common design for core services that are separated away from the startup project to loudly state that "*Any project that requires our services must provide us with some necessary dependencies first*".

Those dependencies would be required as a form of an interface implementation, so when the core library uses `IMyService`, the startup project should inject its own implementation of `IMyService`, say `MyService`.

A good example is the [`IHostApplicationLifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) service that is part of the .Net Generic Host. In a lot of cases, you might want to shut down the application from within your view model, and to do so you will need to call `IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()` which does the job.